# R: Postscript export filename extension on Mac OS X and incorporating mogrify into R

Tags: r, export, postscript, mogrify

I am plotting several graphics in R in a loop and export them as a postscript using `postscript()`.

```
for(i in 1:length(ind)){
  postscript(names(ind[i]))
  par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
  plot(ind[[i]][,c('YEAR','VALUE')],
       type='b',
       main=ind[[i]][1,'NAME'],
       xlab="Time [Years]", 
       ylab="Value [mm]")

dev.off()
}
```

This works all fine but when I have a look at the files in Finder no file extension (e.g .ps) is written to them (I am on Mac OS X 10.8.5). As I want to further process and convert the output images with ImageMagick's `mogrify` I rely on the file extension. Does anyone have a solution for that? When only plotting one file with postscript() then you specify the filename and the extension but how could this be done in a loop?

Another question: is it possible to incorporate command line tools such as mogrify (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) into R so that it could be executed from there (a Windows AND Mac solution would be best)?

Comment: I would guess that `ind` doesn't include file names with extension? Paste one together. `paste(names(ind[i]), ".ps", sep = "")`.

Comment: of course! haven't thought about such a simple solution. thank you!! is there a way how I could incorporate command line tools into R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an extension by `paste(names(ind[i]), ".ps", sep = "")`. If you want to use command line tools, use `shell` or `system`.